# Orchard Module as Partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I had created a module named Orchard.Blogs in my application. Now that blogs view can I make it as a partial view to my other views ? For Ex:  http://localhost/Orchard.Web/Orchard.HrCompany/Payroll/GetPay  is my url and in my GetPay View can I use Orchard.Blogs view as a partial view ?

Comment: Please add some code. What view do you want to re-use? Why have you added an Orchard.Blogs module while it already exists?

Comment: Sorry its not adding, I enabled it. I need that module in my another view as a part.

Comment: And which view of Orchard.Blogs you want to re-use?

Comment: I want the entire blog views to be as a part in my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory you can just use any view you like. However, many views require a view model. For instance, views returned by action methods probably have a view model. If you want to reuse that view, you will have to also provide an instance of that model.

Other views are used by shapes being rendered. If you want to render those views, you will have to actually create an instance of that shape. And if those views expect certain properties to exist on the shape, you will have to set those properties as well.

As you can probably see, this is not very straightforward, as it might potentially involve duplicating a lot of logic to build up the required data (think content part drivers that create shapes, for example).

What I would do instead, is let us know what particular views of the Blogs module you are looking to "reuse". Perhaps there are better ways. For example, there is a BlogArchives widget you might want to use. Or maybe a Projection Widget to render all posts of a particular Blog.

Depending on your exact use case scenario, there is bound to be a proper solution. Blindly reusing views from other modules is not typically done, because of the reasons I just listed.

Answer (score 0):

All the views in orchard called "Shapes", and you can render any shape in any place with "IShapeFactory" interface, you can try the following code:

```
private readonly dynamic _shapeFactory;
public Constructor(IShapeFactory shapeFactory) {
   _shapeFactory = shapeFactory;
}
public void CreateShape(){
    dynamic customShape = _shapeFactory.CustomShape(ViewModel: viewModel);
}
```

This code with search on a view with name "CustomShape", then will render it using the named parameters we send.
On other side, you can display any shape directly in any view like:

```
@Display.CustomShape(ViewModel: viewModel)
```